# Is Backordering an expiring domain still a "first come, first served" situation?

Tags: domain-registration

I'm looking at a domain name that is expired and trying to decide whether it mattes *where* I place my backorder.

[This answer to a similar (but old) question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/3686/7031) indicates that various registrars essentially try to "grab it". The one who grabs it then sells it to anyone that back-ordered it. I assume if multiple people backordered it that they would then auction it amongst those people.

Just wondering if that's still how it works.

Comment: Looks like it is, but I think this is a good question, so I'll leave it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with toomanyairmiles about steering clear of back ordering domains. I've used the service from GoDaddy and have obtained two domains. In my case I knew the industry very well and that websites were only up for a couple of years. I back ordered a few which were expiring soon and others which had already expired which were in the redemption period. They were never registered and after the deletion I got the domains into my account right away in GoDaddy. $20 isn't much to pay.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but my question was about how the mechanics work.

Comment: http://domainnamewire.com/2008/05/14/how-godaddy-domain-name-backorders-work/ A rep from GoDaddy explains it here

Comment: Anagio, that email from the rep is 4 years old.  The rep from SnapNames.com told me that all the Registrar's who have backorders try to "grab" the domain and that it's first come first served.  I'd love to see something more current.  (I think there is no harm in putting in a backorder @ SnapNames and Pool.com b/c you only pay if they get the name for you. So if it IS first-come-first-served, you chances go up. If not, no loss. But Bottom line is that I'd not use GoDaddy for this. You're out $20 or $30 even if you don't get it so they have less incentive (and expertise, IMHO) than the others.

Comment: I'll agree if the others don't charge you unless you get the domain. I suppose it's luck of the draw. I can't imagine there's a waiting list and if you get on it first you'll get the domain first. It probably comes down to which registrar or back order service see's the domain is available first and registers it for you. I wonder if they know the exact time a domain is set to delete or if they all always end say at 12:00am on deletion day.

Answer (score 0):

Back-ordering is a bit of a cartel, they'll take your money but there are no gaurantees that you'll get the domain or a refund.

My advice, steer well clear of it, if you need a domain find one that's available, but don't give the registry's money on the promise that you might get your domain.

Comment: For Pool.com and Snapnames.com, they only charge you if you buy the domain.