# How to get my domain name back before a squatter grabs it?

Tags: domains, expired-domains, domain-squatting

I let my domain name expire by mistake.
And it's even beyond the time where I can reinstate it.
It's now in pending delete status.

What is the best way to get it back before a squatter picks it up?

My registrar said just wait and keep searching for it and when becomes available again to re-register it. But I'm worried the squatters will grab it first.
How do they grab them so quickly?
How can I beat them to it?

Comment: Your registrar should have suggested for you to [back order](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3661/how-to-back-order-domain?rq=1) the domain.

Comment: Because it's a relatively good domain I'm concerned if I do that they'll see it and then back order it for themselves. Or by back ordering it others will see it somehow and back order for themselves as well. Is there any truth in that possibility?

Comment: Better sign up for some [drop catching services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_drop_catching) just in case. Dropcatch.com is one.

Comment: "What is the best way to get it back before a squatter picks it up?" There are possible ways but no "best" one (the only best way was to not forget renewing it... you should make sure that does not happen again), because for "How do they grab them so quickly? How can I beat them to it?" the answer is that obviously they do not do it manually and various registrars "specializes" in such drop catching activities and hence will grab domains they think are worthwhile in **seconds** after them being available. You have no chance to compete against that manually.

Answer (score 1):

Domain name after markets are where you should be looking at.

If it is a good domain name then you will have to outbid the other guys who have also placed a backorder on it. They have already parked it by now and as you suggest it's a good domain name then let's assume it has good traffic and thus it will popup as quite a catch in those lists. (Don't want to sound pessimistic but your chances of getting a good domain back at registration prices and hand registering it are very slim)

You can find out which registrar uses which aftermarkets in usual cases. Go there and find it in upcoming drops/auctions and try to get it.

There are no technical ideas or tricks to get it now as it is gone out of your control and capitalism will take it's course.